# Transferring from one component (page) to another component ( another page)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

what I am trying to achieve here is being able to move to Page1 component from App component by clicking a button.

The result I am getting is

**Page 1
Let's get started
Go!**

The result I want to achieve is

**Page 1**

Please point out what I am doing wrong here. Thank you.

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Page1 from './comps/Page1';

class App extends Component {

  state = { 
    page:0
  }

  HandlePage = () => {
    this.setState({
       page:1
    })
  }

  render() {
    let comp = null;
    if(this.state.page === 1){
      comp = <Page1/>
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {comp}
        <h1>Let's get started!!</h1>
        <div className="button">
          <button 
          type="submit"
          onClick={this.HandlePage}
          >GO</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

//Page 1 Component 
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Page1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Page1;
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you want to change the url or just the rendering.Can you describe it exactly

Comment: I would like to change just the rendering. Sorry, forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a snippet of how you can achieve it by conditional rendering:

```js
const Component = React.Component;

class App extends Component {

  state = { 
    page:0
  }

  handlePage = () => {
    this.setState({
       page:1
    })
  }

  render() {
    let Comp = null;
    if(this.state.page === 1){
      Comp = <Page1/>
    } else if(this.state.page === 0) {
      Comp = <StartPage handlePage={this.handlePage} />
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {Comp}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function StartPage(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Let's get started!!</h1>
      <div className="button">
        <button 
          type="submit"
          onClick={props.handlePage}
        >GO</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

class Page1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

If you have more pages to display, I would encourage you to look at solution like [React Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Is React Router like Redux?

Comment: @YongJunJung No, they are completely different use cases. React Router is a library used for managing routing and redux is for state management

Comment: I see, Thank you!